# Is NServiceBus monitoring agnostic to the transport layer?

Tags: monitoring, nservicebus, prtg

We want to use NServiceBus monitoring feature, but we are using SQL Server on the transport layer instead of MSMQ. I was wondering if NServiceBus monitoring would still work ?

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/monitoring-nservicebus-endpoints

Not really relevant(but, We are using PRTG to monitor the feedback)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it also works for SqlServer transport.
The performance counters are enabled for all transports.

Comment: This is the monitoring i am talking about  http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/monitoring-nservicebus-endpoints  and we are using PRTG to monitor the feedback